# Calling Pythonscript in Java - Slow Python after threading in Java

Tags: java, python, multithreading, jython

I'm invoking a python script from a java class like this:

```
// build aruments for Script
state.get().argv.clear();
state.get().argv.append(new PyString(""));
state.get().argv.append(new PyString("-i" + Ifolder.toString()));
state.get().argv.append(new PyString("-o" + Ofolder.toString()));

// craete PythonInterpreter with those arguments
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter(null, state.get());

// invode LawLinker
interp.execfile("src/scriptx.py");
```

state is a Threadlocal variable that looks like this:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<PySystemState> state = new ThreadLocal<PySystemState>() {
    @Override
    protected PySystemState initialValue() {
        return new PySystemState();
    }

};
```

I had to make it ThreadLocal because otherwise every Thread would have called the Pythonscript with the same arguments i.e. the same state.

So here's the weird part.

If i run only one thread of this at a time, the execution of the script get's faster and faster.
However if i run multiple Threads at a time, the execution alsways takes the same time and that time is quite long...about 5 seconds.
Also it's not creating a new instance of PySystemState ot PythonInterpreter that takes the longest, it's the actuall execution of the script.

Can anyone explain this to me ?

Comment: Does the `PySystemState` have to be static? [This thread](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Multiple-PythonInterpreters-reloading-modules-td1772538.html) seems to imply that they shouldn't be. And the only reason they have to be thread-local is because they're static, right?

Comment: It doesn't need to be static, tbh i don't know why it is. It needs to be Threadlocal because every Thread has to set it's own state for the interpreter. I can't just put it into the threaded method because that will give me the same performace break.

Comment: If it weren't static, it wouldn't need to be Threadlocal, it could just be a local variable or instance variable the thread function or object. Only static/global variables ever need to be thread-local.

Comment: Meanwhile, issues [#1340](http://bugs.jython.org/issue1340), [#1868602](http://bugs.jython.org/issue1868602), and [#607391](http://bugs.jython.org/issue607391) seem to imply that, at least as of 2.5.3, there are various static/global variables in/used by `PySystemState`, so even if you do keep the `PySystemState` itself local or thread-local, it's not actually safe—and a bunch of extra locks have been added which may end up serializing your code GIT-style  even when it _is_ safe. Can you tell whether your threads are actually running in parallel (e.g., 4 cores at 100% instead of 100/0/0/0)?

Comment: You're right it does work as a local variable as well but i don't get the same performance as I do with TheadLocal if I only run one Thread at a time. For some reason the execution of the Script takes longer.

Comment: What makes you think you have to run one thread at a time if you use local or instance variables? That's not how threads work. You only need thread-local for things that would otherwise be shared (like static/global variables, or instances that you explicitly share).

Comment: If i declare the variable not static and not globale, the state for all executions of the script seems to be the same. That's why I wen't for ThreadLocal.

Comment: A non-static local variable cannot be accessed by other instances of the same function, whether they're in the same thread or not. So it sounds like you have a problem with your design or a serious bug in jython or something, and, rather than trying to understand it, you've just papered it over by trying random things until something seemed to work. When you do that kind of thing, it's pretty much impossible to debug the results.

Comment: it isnt local. I can't make it lokal, because then the performance breaks down, for a reason I can't understand. If the variable is NOT local and there is no threading then the performance is right and there are no problems. If i make it local (still no threading), the performanc breaks but still not problems. So I wanted to make it NOT local to gain performance but then I have to make it threadlocal with appearantly breaks performance again.